# .Content is returning NULL

Tags: null, restsharp

I am trying to connect to an API. I have followed the documentation, but the .Content is returning NULL. Can anyone assist me in figuring out why? I'm targeting .NET 4.5.2 and using the latest version of RestSharp (106.5.4).

```
    var tokenclient = new RestClient("[api url]");
    var tokenrequest = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
    tokenrequest.AddParameter("undefined", "client_id=xxx&client_secret=xxx&grant_type=client_credentials", ParameterType.RequestBody);
    tokenrequest.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
    tokenrequest.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    tokenrequest.AddHeader("grant_type", "client_credentials");
    IRestResponse tokenreceived = tokenclient.Execute(tokenrequest);
    var content = tokenreceived.Content; <-- .Content is returning NULL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to add this line above the new RestClient(...)

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls; 
        var tokenclient = new RestClient("[api-url]");
```

https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/942